# What can be that pure white grease used within a coffee mill?

Tags: lubrication

Earlier today I decided it was time to disassemble my Kalita Nice Cut coffee mill and clean it a bit.

I initially removed the 2 huge screws to take out the front part where the burrs are located (that actually mill the beans) and cleaned that.

Then I wondered what is that part between the motor (rear) and the burrs. Does that need some adjustment or cleaning? So I unscrewed that middle block which was made of 2 parts, having gears on each side.

I was amazed at how clean this was, after years and years of utilization. Anyway, there was pure white grease everywhere.

What can be that pure white grease, which is usually found in kitchen appliances? Can it be handled safely? (I think the gears where made of ceramic(?)).

[unfortunately I didn't think of taking pictures at the time]

Comment: Assuming it's a matter of taking some screws out, for the sake of helping us answer this question, adding some photos would really help :)

Comment: Grease used in a device for food products is probably food safe type, instead of the regular wheel bearing white grease.  Besides not tasting that good it should be safe.  Would check the seals between the gear housing and the burr section.  Mixing of coffee and grease in the gears might not be good for long life of the mill, coffee might taste different also.

Comment: Can't think a picture of white greasy gears is going to help identify the specific white grease, really, @MiG

Comment: I had to replace a gear in a Kitchen Aid mixer years ago.  The existing gear set had grease on it, and the new gear came with a tube of grease.  I sure that grease has to be food safe.  I don't think you have anything to worry about.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about small appliances are off topic.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Can see colour, consistency, viscosity (based on how it has spread inside) etc from that. It would at least narrow it down a bit.

Comment: @MIG Actually the gear part was not so easy to re-assemble, + holding and contaminating these greasy things also...

Comment: @crip659 The gear section was amazingly clean. There is a shaft between the gears and burrs that seems to be well insulated.

Answer (score 5):

Food-Safe grease is a common product. Exactly which one you have you'd have to ask the makers of your mill. However, since the area appears from your description to be well-sealed against contamination from the outside, you can probably just leave it alone, unless the owner's manual specifies a regreasing interval.

Two examples, there are *many* others, just ask your search engine of choice **food safe grease** *(no endorsement implied)*

[image: Lubriplate L0231-098 FG image from VXB.com]

[image: CRC Multipurpose Food Grade Grease NLGI image from spsindustrial.com]

Answer (score 0):

Many types of grease exist, so it will be hard to be sure.

However, early white greases were lithium based, what a white grease may contain now may be different.

Comment: Usually think white grease used/know  for wheel bearing grease.